# Java Fibonacci Series- Output is going in negative value even though the program is correct

Tags: java, loops, fibonacci

I am unable to get the expected output only for the number 48 for a Fibonacci series program. The program is executed properly in order but at one point it changes to negative which should not happen in the Fibonacci series.

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Hello {

public static void main(String[] args) {

//Your Code Here 
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); int s = sc.nextInt();

int a = 0; int b = 1;

int c = a+b;

System.out.print(a+" "+b);

for (int i=3; i<=s; ++i){

c=a+b;

System.out.print(" "+c);

a=b;

b=c;

}
```

input:

48

Expected Output:

0112358 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 17 711 28657 46368 75025 121393 196418 317811 514229 832040 1346269 217830 9 3524578 5702887 9227465 14930352 24157817 39088169 63245986 10233415 5 165580141 267914296 433494437 701408733 1134903170 1836311903 29712 15073

Output:

0112358 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765 10946 17 711 28657 46368 75025 121393 196418 317811 514229 832040 1346269 217830 9 3524578 5702887 9227465 14930352 24157817 39088169 63245986 10233415 5 165580141 267914296 433494437 701408733 1134903170 1836311903 -1323 752223

For the output, i have attached an image below,
[image: the output that i got and the expected output is attached]

Comment: Overflow.  Integer overflow.  And signed integer wraparound.

Comment: Why didn't you simply paste the output into the StackOverflow window as text?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Because he's working with a postmodern GUI that doesn't support such outdated concepts.  (You'll notice that he didn't even post a conventional screenshot, but rather, what appears to be a cellphone photograph of his monitor.) [And apologies for the sarcasm...]

Comment: I was going to say, "Because text is for boomers."

Comment: Use `BigInteger`.  Also, FYI -- since the C++ and C tags were removed, you don't have such a type in C or C++, and would have to create your own big integer class or use an existing one from a third-party.

Comment: To me, making sure the font is small enough, standing away from the monitor, taking out the camera, focusing it, snapping a picture, maybe more than once to make sure everything fits, then saving that picture to an image, uploading it to stackoverflow, (I'm tired already) -- all that instead of copying and pasting text.  I just don't get why so many beginners think that taking pictures is easier than a couple of strokes on the keyboard.

Comment: *Output is going in negative value even though the program is correct*  The "program is correct" part is in error.  The program is not correct.

Comment: I got the output after using the long data type, instead of int. Thank you all for answering.

Comment: @AFRATARANUMA Thanks for pasting the more-useful text.  The "correct" next number 2971215073 is a 32-bit number, meaning it cannot be represented as a 32-bit *signed* integer, which supports only values from -2147483648 to 2147483647.  Interpreted as a signed integer, 2971215073 turns into -1323752223, which is the wrong number you got.  This is [*two's complement arithmetic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: @AFRATARANUMA -- [See this using BigInteger](https://ideone.com/gQ5zgi).